# Differentiable applications

Tags: analysis

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an application defined by $\varphi (x) =f(x).g(x)$, where $f,g: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ are linear functional. Prove that $\varphi'(x)$ exists.

I found that $\varphi'(x)v=f(v)g(x)+f(x)g(v)$, where $x,v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.
When I went to prove the existence of the derivative by definition($\varphi(z+h)=\varphi (z) + \varphi '(z)h + r(h)$), I found the limit

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left ( h \right )g\left ( h \right ))}{\left \| h \right \|}$

But I can not prove that this limit is zero

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your post to provide context, e.g. what have you tried? Where are you stuck? You'll find that these sorts of questions are generally better-received here than those of the form "here is my problem, solve it for me."